# Newark transit from terminal B to terminal A on separate itineraries

Tags: transit, ewr, jetblue

I am arriving at Newark Airport terminal B on an international flight. Am not a US citizen or resident.

I have a connecting flight to Boston from terminal A on JetBlue. This was purchased on a separate itinerary.

I have one bag for check in

I have two questions

1. On arrival at terminal B, after going through immigration, baggage claim and customs, I presume that I have to take the AirTrain to terminal V. Where is this located in Terminal B?
2. Is it possible to check in my bag for the connecting flight at terminal B itself? (is there a JetBlue counter there?) Or do I have to take it to terminal A and check it in and get my boarding pass.

Thanks in advance for all help and inputs

Answer (score 8):

When your flight lands in terminal B, you'll have to go through immigration to the front of the airport. From there, you'll see signs directing you to the Airtrain.

Newark puts different airlines into different terminals so you won't be able to check your bag in terminal B. You'll have to go to terminal A to do so.

Welcome to NJ!

EDIT: Here's what you should look for in Terminal B:
[image]